# Querying UUID Type Values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, clojure, uuid, monger

Documents stored in a collection include a `UUID` type value when they are inserted and when they are returned from Monger's `find-maps` function. For example:

```
{:_id "5515e636314525806f24ceb3"
 :a #uuid "cfda7109-6e50-44c0-b13d-48712f7509a1"}
```

However when I specify query with this criterion:

```
(find-maps db collection {:a #uuid "cfda7109-6e50-44c0-b13d-48712f7509a1"})
```

or this:

```
(find-maps db collection {:a "cfda7109-6e50-44c0-b13d-48712f7509a1"})
```

no results are returned. Do I need to use a type converter, or should I just store :a as some other type? Or, perhaps there is some other way?

Comment: Not very helpful to say it, but if I store that doc using monger in a test collection, `(find-maps db collection {:a #uuid "cfda7109-6e50-44c0-b13d-48712f7509a1"})` retrieves it successfully for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting using the `fromString` static method of `java.util.UUID`:

```
(ns my.project
  (import [java.util UUID]))

(find-maps db collection {:a (UUID/fromString "cfda7109-6e50-44c0-b13d-48712f7509a1")})
```

Comment: Why does this differ from the #uuid reader macro tagged literal version? (avail since clojure 1.4, apparently)